# Go Dynamically Removing HTML onClick

Tags: html, go

I'm new to Go. I'm understanding the basics more and more but now I'm trying to learn how to interface the code with HTML.

My simple scenario is that I have a single web page with a list that's created by Go fetching information from a database, then building the html page from a group of templates. All I want is to make a simple list that will allow me to somehow mark it as complete/done when the `<div>` is clicked or something. Also, to be able to fully delete a "row" in my webpage list, a div basically.

So my list will indicate something is complete (I assume I must use Go to alter the css) and delete an item (completely remove that block of html). And remember, these items are stored in a database, so I must be able to identify the specific item.

Any help, ideas, resources, pseudocode, pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your thinking is incorrect. Your server-side language won't edit your markup and/or css. Your server side language (Go) only serves markup for the browser to render. You can then either dynamically manipulate it via a client side language (Javascript) or, have your page post back to your Go which serves _different_ markup. Go cannot alter the content in the browser unless it serves up _different_ markup for the browser to render (a full page refresh, or a combination of client + server.. AJAX).

Comment: Sounds like you need to start from the start on building Go web apps see -- http://lincolnloop.com/blog/djangonaut-building-webapp-go-gorilla/ which points to https://bitbucket.org/yml/gowebexp/ which is apparently supposed to be a slightly-more-than-trivial app.

Answer (score 1):

In web development, there are two "ends" where code executes; the browser and the server, aka. the front-end and the back-end.

A "click" happens in the browser and will execute code in the browser. That "browser-code" in turn may or may not contact the server for additional information and then render that information to the browser.

That means; the server has no control over what happens in the browser* and vice versa. That's the basics of web development.

Go is a language good for building servers. Javacript is the language that most browsers understand. What you need is Javascript, not Go.

* <sub>this is not entirely true but good enough as a base to start learning.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm pretty sure that php can work with html elements (not sure how far that can go, probably not far), such as form validation, so all I wanted to do was eliminate that Go can in no way change any html elements, and that I MUST use ajax in order to accomplish this.

Comment: hmm that's not entirely so. Go can parse and render HTML templates, but the onclick handler is always javascript (this is true for php as well). cheers!

Comment: So then would you say that indeed, the best way to remove an html element when a user clicks, (as well as delete it from the db), would be to use ajax? And Go's only role would be to create the page and receive the deletion from ajax and go delete it in the db?